# Derivative of Rodrigue's rotation formula

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, rotations, cross-product

I'm reading this book that is talking about [Rodrigue's rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) that says that to rotate a vector $\mathbf{v}$ about a rotation axis $\mathbf{n}$ and through an angle $\theta$, you need to multiply $\mathbf{v}$ by the matrix $\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{n}, \theta)$ given below, where $[\mathbf{n}]_\times$ is the matrix representing the linear transformation $\mathbf{w} \to \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{w}$, i.e $$[\mathbf{n}]_\times = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -n_z& n_y \\ n_z & 0 & -n_x \\ -n_y & -n_x & 0\end{bmatrix}$$.

[image]

My issue is with with the last part above. I am not able to derive that Jacobian matrix formula on my own $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Rv}}{\partial \mathbf{\omega}^T}$. Can you kindly give me a more direct derivation of that from the formula? This is from page 47 in Szeliski's book on Computer Vision, which you can find legally online in the author's website [here](https://szeliski.org/Book/).

Answer (score 1):

For typing convenience, define the matrices $(V,W)$ as
$$\eqalign{
V &= [v]_{\times} &\implies \,Vw = v\times w \\ 
W &= [w]_{\times} &\implies Wv = w\times v \\
Wv &= w\times v &\;=\; -v\times w = -Vw \\ 
}$$
Then what the last paragraph is saying is
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\approx}
\def\p{\partial}
&R \a (I + W) \\
&Rv \a (v + Wv) \;=\; (v - Vw) \\
&\frac{\p(Rv)}{\p w} \a \;-V \\\\
}$$